# How to toggle from file to NERDtree showing the directory that keeps the file in current window?

Tags: plugin-nerdtree

When I open a vertical split by providing the path to a directory with `:vsplit /my/dir` the split window opens with NERDtree showing the directory. I then open a file `/my/dir/file`. I would then love to switch back to the inital view showing NERDtree with `/my/dir` in this window again as before.

Background:
I often compare/copy stuff from a file in one location to/from a file in a completely different location. Doing this, I would love to be able to browse both locations. I can browse one location with my default NERDtree showing on the left. For browsing the 2nd location, I would love to have the above capability.

Comment: If you don't mind giving up on NERDtree, the builtin in Netrw plugin has a command `:Rexplore` (`:Rex` for short) that toggles a window between the last Netrw display and the last Netrw-edited file.

Comment: Obligatory: http://vimcasts.org/blog/2013/01/oil-and-vinegar-split-windows-and-project-drawer/

Comment: @D.BenKnoble thanks a lot for this interesting article! It looks very promising and I'll give it a try :)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I'm still working based on the builtin Netrw plugin and though still have to internelize the differences, like it a lot so far, thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind giving up on NERDtree, the builtin in Netrw plugin has a command `:Rexplore` (`:Rex` for short) that toggles a window between the last Netrw display and the last Netrw-edited file.

An obligatory [article about favoring same-window-style directory browsing to project-tree-style directory browsing](http://vimcasts.org/blog/2013/01/oil-and-vinegar-split-windows-and-project-drawer/).